# What is the correct way to reprocess backed up data in Cassandra using Spark from a Kafka source?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, cassandra

We have a standard Kafka - Spark - Cassandra pipeline structure. (using scala)

Messages are consumed by the spark job from Kafka, and in case the spark job is unable to process data due to some issue(job down, resource issues etc) we store the unprocessed messages in a table in Cassandra (with columns - raw message, timestamp, topic, and error).

What is the best way to reprocess this data once the job is up and running again? Since there would also be other new messages in Kafka by then.

Comment: What issues are you having following the datastax spark connector documentation to read from Cassandra?

Comment: No problems in that area, but there would be other issues as it a time series data. Before I begin to tackle those I wanted to know if this is the best way to begin, or if there are other standard best practices to handle this kind of a situation

Answer (score 2):

Kafka has a mechanism that keeps track of which messages have been consumed and stores the state for each consumer group as an "offset".

Your Spark application uses the offset so it doesn't go back and process all the messages again -- it just goes back to the last message it consumed, and committed an offset for, in the stream and process the next one. Cheers!

Comment: So if the spark job fails after a few messages have been consumed by it before it is able to write the data to Cassandra, when the spark job starts again it will consume the same messages from Kafka? Will there be no data loss in this case? I have set enable.auto.commit = true if it helps

Comment: The case I'm concerned about is:
1.Spark consumes a message from kafka

2.Before it has finished processing this message, the job fails and is unable to write the data to Cassandra.

3.When the spark job restarts it will begin consuming from the next message in Kafka

How to recover this lost message?

Comment: Note: Spark doesn't store offsets in Kafka unless explicitly told to, e.g. `kafka.group.id` option

Comment: @cst No, it will not resume consuming the next message. It would resume from the previously committed offset (which might be a message already written successfully to the database), only if you have set `kafka.group.id` to a static value. Messages are not removed from Kafka when consumed. Otherwise, it'll use your `startingOffsets` option (or default  to the very end of the topic, and skip all unconsumed events since the app stopped)